# If Daenerys was willing to help these people out, why didn't she do it from the beginning?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In "Beyond the Wall" (*Game of Thrones*, S07E06),

> Daenerys flies with her dragons to help Jon and Co.

But if leaving Dragonstone with her Dragons and travel across Westeros to risk her life and the life of her dragons was an acceptable option to Daenerys .... why did she not offer her help from the beginning?

She could fly to the wall with Jon and a few others, search for a small group of wights, drop down, they would grab a wight, and then fly back.

Why did Daenerys not help them from the get-go?

Comment: It wasn't urgent till then

Answer (score 13):

**Season 7 Episode 6 Spoilers**

I'll make the answer a little more specific. Daenerys was extremely counseled not to do so, mainly by Tyrion. When she received the raven, she wanted to go and went while counseled otherwise. Tyrion said in all the words for her to do nothing, but even so, she went.

> **Tyrion** - You can't! The most important person in the world can't fly to the most dangerous place in the world.
>
> **Danaerys** - Who else can?
>
> **Tyrion** - No one. They knew the risk when they left. You can't win the throne if you're dead. You can't break the wheel if you're dead.
>
> **Danaerys** - So what would you have me do?
>
> **Tyrion** - Nothing. Sometimes nothing is the hardest thing to do. If you die we're all lost. Everyone, everything.
>
> **Danaerys** - You told me to do nothing before and I've listened to you. I'm not doing nothing again.

*From Game of Thrones: Season 7 Episode 6*

That's it. When things got really serious, she couldn't wait.

Comment: Nitpick: raven, not crow. There is [a difference](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/9e/b8/44/9eb844586a23f84cb3b9a96c8b90dbf6--counting-crows-crows-ravens.jpg).

Answer (score 4):

**Season 7 Episode 6 Spoilers**

Daenerys didn't believe in Others like most of Westeros don't. So it was unreasonable to expect from her to go and fight the dead when she doesn't believe they exist and to abandon the war she is waging. She started to believe after seeing Others carved in obsidian caves on Dragonstone when Jon showed her.

But it is more likely that she went now because it was personal for her. What many fans anticipate and as she said herself, she "got used" to King Jon. And Ser Jorah is there also for whom she already have strong feelings, althought that love may be of a friend. So when she received the message they are in danger, it must have been emotions starting to work. Going there was not a reasonable thing to do, as you could see, but emotional one. Which emotions are stronger, towards Jon or Jorah, or both, doesn't really matter and we will see more of those in episodes to come.

So she didn't help them before because she didn't feel like there was reason to. She helped them now probably because of personal feelings. She will be focused on Night King from now on obviously, but this understanding came **AFTER** she helped them and saw with her own eyes what the army of dead is. Until then she couldn't comprehend what danger that really is. So she went there more because of those specific people or person that needed her help, than because of simple awareness that she must join the fight against the night.

Comment: I think guilt also plays a role. She agreed to this harebrained scheme and she feels responsible for possibly losing yet another group of allies. She couldn't do anything to save the Greyjoys, the Martells or Tyrells because by the time she heard about it, it was all over. Here she _can_ do something and she won't stand idly by when there's still a chance to save them.